# CronJob not sending out mails via PHP Mailer

Tags: php, bash, cron, phpmailer

I have a bash script which calls out to PHP Mailer if the set parameters are correct, which then sends out a mail to the intended recipients. This is working fine when I work on the command line.

```
./compare.sh
```

However when I try to integrate the same within cron, I do not receive any emails.

```
49 21 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /full-path/compare.sh
```

I have tried running the cronjob as the apache user, but that did not work.

In the maillog, it is showing from=root, to=root. I have tries MAILTO and MAILFROM in the crontab, but had no luck.

I am running php56 on CentOS 7 machine.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are seeing `from=root to=root`, that possibly suggests your script produced errors (or other output worth reviewing) and the result was emailed to `root` per normal cron behavior. Check root's email account if you can - `sudo su -` to become root and `mail` (install `mailx` via yum if you don't have the `mail` command)

Comment: Or redirect the output of your command to a logfile you can view `/full-path/compare.sh >> /tmp/yourcron.log 2>&1`  You will probably need to post at least some of the contents of both the `compare.sh` script and the PHP code it executes for us to help any further.

Comment: Try running the command as root - my guess is probably you're `include` ing a file with a relative path that isn't found when you don't run the script from it's directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. There was a file which included using a relative path. Once I added the full path for that file, the cronjob ran successfully.